# Why I'm getting documents not included in the projection?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these 2 documents in my collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5722042f8648ba1d04c65dad"), 
    "companyId" : ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e"), 
    "applicationId" : ObjectId("5710e3994df37620e84808a8"), 
    "steps" : [ 
        { 
            "id" : NumberLong(0), 
            "responsiveUser" : "57206f9362d0260fd0af59b6", 
            "stepOnRejection" : NumberLong(0), 
            "notification" : "test" 
        },
        { 
            "id" : NumberLong(1), 
            "responsiveUser" : "57206fd562d0261034075f70", 
            "stepOnRejection" : NumberLong(1), 
            "notification" : "test1" 
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5728f317a8f9ba14187b84f8"), 
    "companyId" : ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e"), 
    "applicationId" : ObjectId("5710e3994df37620e84808a8"), 
    "steps" : [ 
        { 
            "id" : NumberLong(0), 
            "responsiveUser" : "57206f9362d0260fd0af59b6", 
            "stepOnRejection" : NumberLong(0), 
            "notification" : "erter" 
        },
        { 
            "id" : NumberLong(1), 
            "responsiveUser" : "57206f9362d0260fd0af59b6", 
            "stepOnRejection" : NumberLong(1), 
            "notification" : "3232" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the document with the **max** `_id` and the `id` **that equals 0** from a document inside of the `steps` array. I also have a projection that is supposed to show **only** the `id` of the matched element and nothing else.

Here is my query:

```
collection
    .find(new Document("companyId", companyId)
        .append("applicationId", applicationId)
        .append("steps", 
                 new Document("$elemMatch", 
                 new Document("id", 0))))
    .sort(new Document("_id", 1))
    .limit(1)
    .projection(new Document("steps.id", 1)
    .append("_id", 0));
```

And it returns:

```
Document{{steps=[Document{{id=0}}, Document{{id=1}}]}}
```

Why is it returning 2 documents instead of 1?

The result should be looking like:

```
Document{{id=0}}
```

What am I missing here? I know that is something basic, but I really can't spot my mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query document tells Mongo to return those documents where in the 'steps' array they have a document where `id: 0`. You are NOT telling Mongo to return ONLY that field. You can use `$elemMatch` inside the projection document to get what you want (I'm writing this in the Mongo shell syntax because I'm not too familiar with the Java syntax):

```
{   steps: { $elemMatch: { id: 0 } }, 
    'steps.id': 1, 
    _id: 0
}
```